# Using eventListener to change stroke style after mobile movement

Tags: javascript, canvas, addeventlistener, event-listener, devicemotion

I'm trying to get the strokeStyle to change from black to red after the phone moves, but I can't seem to make it work! I want to be able to pull this up on my phone, and when I move the phone the curves on canvas will turn to blue.

Here is the code I have :

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
  var j = 12.5 * i;
  ctx.moveTo(-200 + j, 0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(175 + j, 330, 1 + j, 600, j, 600);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(-150 + j, 750, 250 + j, 800, j + 75, 850);
  //ctx.bezierCurveTo(200+j,850, 100+j, 1000, j, 1000);                                                           
}
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", handleDeviceMotion, true)

function handleDeviceMotion(e) {
  var x = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
  var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
  var z = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
  document.getElementById("c").innerText = x;
  document.getElementById("c").innerText = z;
  document.getElementById("c").innerText = y;

  setStrokeColor(ctx);
}

function setStrokeColor() {
  document.getElementById("c").strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
}
//setBackgroundColor('x', color);                                                                                 
//setBackgroundColor('y', color);                                                                                 
//setBackgroundColor('z', color);                                                                                 
//function setBackgroundColor(var, color) {                                                                       
//  document.getElementbyId(var).color = "blue";                                                                  

ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="1200" height="1000" style="border: 1 px solid     #c3c3c3" ;>                                      
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Not sure if the code was actual code, but there were some issues I cleaned up when moving it to a SO snippet. Typos in function names, using `event` instead of `e`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to change the color of lines once they've been drawn. One option is to erase (or reset the state of the canvas to clean), then redraw the lines with the new color. Something along these lines:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

function drawLines(color) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    var j = 12.5 * i;
    ctx.moveTo(-200 + j, 0);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(175 + j, 330, 1 + j, 600, j, 600);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(-150 + j, 750, 250 + j, 800, j + 75, 850);
  }

  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = color;
  ctx.stroke();
}


drawLines('#000000');

function handleDeviceMotion(e) {

  // clear the lines
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  drawLines('#FF0000');

  var x = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.x;
  var y = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.y;
  var z = e.accelerationIncludingGravity.z;
  document.getElementById("c").innerText = x;
  document.getElementById("c").innerText = z;
  document.getElementById("c").innerText = y;
}


document.getElementById("simulateMotion").addEventListener('click', function() {

  var e = {
    accelerationIncludingGravity: {
      x: 1,
      y: 1,
      z: 1
    }
  }

  handleDeviceMotion(e);
});
```

```html
<button id="simulateMotion">Simulate Motion</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<canvas id="c" width="1200" height="1000" style="border: 1 px solid     #c3c3c3" ;>                                      
    </canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you Brett!  Oh darn okay.  Okay so I;m a little confused what to change to make the code actually responsive to device motion?  I wasn't sure what to put as the event in eventListener...

Comment: The event listener on the device motion was ok, I think. For the demo in this site I had to use a different event listener so it could be tested.